# picture web2py python

Tags: python, web2py

Hello I'm having a problem displaying a picture in web2py. I know it similar to writing HTML code for some reason the picture doesn't appear. Maybe its a syntax error or maybe I've been looking at the code for to long to tell.

Comment: never used this lib but open the page in browser if you can, view source code and find the path your code generates. make sure it's correct (my guess is it's not).

Comment: yes the path is correct

Comment: Check the permissions on the upload folder. Whatever user the server as running as will need read and execute permissions or else it won't be able to see the `uploads/` folder.

Comment: how do i check for permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web2py doesn't serve URLs like that. See the book section on [dispatching](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#Dispatching). The URL must specify an application, controller, and function (and optionally args and/or vars), and the function should retrieve and return the requested file. For details, see the book section on [uploads](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07?search=def+download#SQLFORM-and-uploads) as well as the [`download()` function](https://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/applications/welcome/controllers/default.py#42) in the scaffolding app.

The only exception is for files in the `/static` folder within the application -- they can be served directly via URLs like `/myapp/static/path/to/file.ext`. If pic.png is a static file, then you should put it in the `/static` folder.